ASP-NET, muestra html en vez de renderizar. API MINIMA
Estoy aprendiendo ASP NET.
Empeze desarrollando un CRUD sencillo con api minima, todo directamente en VSCode. Me parecio que en VsCode es mas limpio y minimalista trabajar.
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.MapGet("/", async (HttpContext context) => {
    await context.Response.SendFileAsync("wwwroot/index.html");
    }
); 

Posteriormente quise empezar otro pequeño proyecto, y me pase a VISUAL STUDIO.
Y resulta que el codigo anterior cuando me levanta el servidor, el archivo index.html se sirve pero no renderiza la pagina. Mas bien muestra el codigo HTML en pantalla.
Cuando ejecuto un proyecto en Visual Studio Code, desde la CLI, con "dotnet run" todo funciona perfecto.
Pero en Visual Studio no me funciona. Desconozco si es por el tipo de server que ejecuta o no se. Por lo tanto encontre esta solucion  y tuve que añádirle la siguiente linea al manejador del endpoint:
 context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";

Quisiera preguntarles cual es el inconveniente de que sea necesario este código, en Visual Studio y no en VSCode.
Y tambien consultarles, si es correcto usar VSCode para .NET, mas bien ASP. O deberia acostumbrarme e ir aprendiendo Visual Studio? Muchas gracias.

todo lo que decis es correcto... visual studio es mucho mas comodo como entorno.. code es mas ligero y sencillo, pero carece de algunas funcionalidades (aunque no te van a matar).. lo raro, es que se ejecuten distinto en los dos entornos...

No sé el motivo, supongo que levantan servidore web distintos o con distinta configuración
Para retornar un archivo html, lo que yo hago es:

//esto es para poder inyectar IFileProvider al endpoint y obtener la ruta fisica
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot")));

//otras configuraciones

var app = builder.Build();

//otras configuraciones

app.MapGet("/", (IFileProvider fileProvider) => {
    var filePath = fileProvider.GetFileInfo("index.html").PhysicalPath;
    return Results.File(filePath , "text/html");
});


Sobre Visual Studio vs VScode, no te puedo responder, yo uso Visual Studio para todo (C#, javascript, css,html, php, python) sin mayor problema, por lo que nunca he tenido la necesidad de probar VScode

Pfsss Pinche asp JAJAJA es un lio!!! Bueno creo que seguire mi ruta!! Y me obligare a usar Visual Studio para .NET. Porque es mas complejo de usar que VSCode. Asi que gracias.
